# Como instanciar un objeto para crear un documento en mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hola buenas soy nuevo en esto, tengo entendido que para crear el modelo de un esquema es asi=>

```
var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);

  var movie      = new Movie(); //instanciamos mi objeto user(Documents are instances of our model)
movie.name     = 'admin1';
movie.email    = 'fmls1989@gmail.com';
movie.password = 'Berna123';
movie.age      = 28;
```

Pero claro yo quiero hacerlo  asi pero no me deja ya que pone que Movie ya esta definido, querria despues insertar peliculas aleatoriamente con un loop, como lo puedo hacer?  =>

```
class Movie{
Constructor(name, email, password, age){
  this._name = name;
  this._email = email;
  this._password = password;
  this._age = age;
}
```

}

var movieName = new Movie('Harry Potter', 'fmls1989@gmail.com', 'Berna123', 28);

```js
'use strict';

//1. Dependencies & Connecting
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/peliculas-random", function(err){
    if (err) console.log('error');
    else console.log('connection has been made');
});

//2. General Schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//3. Movie Schema
var movieSchema = new Schema({
    name:{type:String, required:true, unique: false},
    lastname:{type:String},
    email:{type:String},
    password:{type:String},
    age:{type:Number},
});

//Mongoose Paginate
movieSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

//4. Constructor of my Schema
var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);

//5. Populating Collection
function createMovie(){

    var movie      = new Movie(); //instanciamos mi objeto user(Documents are instances of our model)
    movie.name     = 'admin1';
    movie.email    = 'fmls1989@gmail.com';
    movie.password = 'Berna123';
    movie.age      = 28;

    movie.save(function(err){ // Sving instance of my model
        if (err) console.log('There is an error: ' + err.message);
        else console.log('Movie created successfully');
    });
    console.log(movie);
}
createMovie();

// class Movie{
//     Constructor(name, email, password, age){
//       this._name = name;
//       this._email = email;
//       this._password = password;
//       this._age = age;
//     }
// }
//
// var movieName = new Movie('Harry Potter', 'fmls1989@gmail.com', 'Berna123', 28);
//
//
// mongoose.connection.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para poder crear una instancia de tu modelo, tienes que enviarle un objeto con los parámetros que require, en el caso de tu entidad Movie sería algo así:

```
var movie = new Movie({
    name: 'admin1',
    email: 'fmls1989@gmail.com',
    password: 'Berna123',
    age: 28    
})
```

De esta manera no deberías de tener problemas al crear multiples instancias usando un loop, solamente tendrás que hacer tu `movie.save()` en cada iteración de tu ciclo.